# MSMQ - how to Communicate between two application

Tags: msmq, msmq-wcf, lokad-cqrs

I started looking into MSMQ very recently so i have basic doubts . If two application needs to communicate lets say server and client I think both will share the same MQ address and when the client update then the Server will be having the MSMQ watcher which will listen to the message pick and use it. So according to me there are three component we need

Client  - which knows the Queue location

Queue watcher - which watches the queue

service -- to which queue watcher will send the message to

Comment: What do you mean by "both will share the same MQ address"?

Do you mean both machines put messages into a common queue and an application works out which message is for which machine?

Why don't you have a queue on the server that the client sends to and a different queue on the client that the server sends to?

Comment: Then you wouldn't need a separate MSMQ watcher. Each client and server application watches the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Tom Hollander wrote an excellent series of three articles on WCF and MSMQ.  They helped me alot when I had to build an application to communicate via MSMQ.  There is a third article but Stack Overflow won't let me post since I'm a new user.  You can find the link to it from the 2nd article.

[MSMQ, WCF and IIS: Getting them to play nice (Part 1)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2008/07/12/msmq-wcf-and-iis-getting-them-to-play-nice-part-1.aspx)

[MSMQ, WCF and IIS: Getting them to play nice (Part 2)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2008/07/13/msmq-wcf-and-iis-getting-them-to-play-nice-part-2.aspx)